# Device to Test Radioactive Beverage

Tags: radioactivity

In one scene of the movie "Edge of Darkness", the protagonist uses a device to test the radioactivity of milk in a glass container by placing the device near but outside the container. What is this device called, and is it sold to the public?

Comment: There are a variety of radiation detection technologies that can be packaged in a portable and self-contained form, but assuming that something you saw in a movie represents a real, deployed technology is, well, a little optimistic.

Comment: Also, *which* Edge of Darkness? The [2010 Mel Gibson](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1226273/) movie version or the original [1985 BBC miniseries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_of_Darkness) version?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - the 2010 Mel Gibson movie.

Comment: As a second comment if you are interested in $^{210}\mathrm{Po}$ in particular, using a gamma sensitive detector is dicey: the primary decay is alpha and [the branch that includes a gamma is at the $10^{-5}$ level](http://ie.lbl.gov/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=840210) meaning that a lethal dose produces less gamma radiation than the cosmic and environmental background. You'd have to be willing to integrate a while to be sure.

Comment: @dmckee So alpha detectors are uncommon, at least for the average joe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20594/discussion-between-user12707-and-dmckee). If you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a portable, pocket size radiation detector like this one that United Nuclear sells:

http://unitednuclear.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=2_78

I would try Amazon though first to see if you can find a better price.